# How to find Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

How to evaluate $\int_t^\infty e^{-sx}f(x)dx$ using laplace transform properties?

Comment: @Litum: Do you have any information about $t$?

Comment: Do you mean you want to express that integral in terms of the laplace transform of $f$?

Comment: @fgp: I think if $t$ be the period of $f(x)$ then we could write some calculations.

Comment: @BabakSorouh Who says that $f$ is periodic? It think what you might be looking for is the relationship between the laplace transform of $f$ and that of $f$ shifted by $t$.

Comment: @fgp: Nobody says. It seems that we can only find a relationship between the laplace transform of f and ...as you noted. Doesn't it?

Comment: $t$ is not the period of $f$ it is just the argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can interpret that integral as the laplace transform of $f$ multiplied with a shifted step function $H$. Since a multiplication in the time domain maps to a convolution in the frequency domain, and since the laplace transform of $H(t-a)$ is $\frac{e^{-as}}{s}$ you get $$
\int_t^{\infty} e^{-sx}f(x)dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} f(x)H(x-t) dx = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\cdot\infty}^{\sigma+i\cdot\infty}F(u)\frac{e^{-t(s-u)}}{s-u} du 
$$
where $$\begin{eqnarray}
  F(s) &=& \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}f(x)dx \\
  H(x) &=& \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} 
\end{eqnarray}$$
and $\sigma$ lies within convergence region of $F$.

Comment: What are the differences between LST and LT?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \text{Unit Step Fuction : } \begin{eqnarray}
    u(t-c)  \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } t > c  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} 
\end{eqnarray} $$
$$ \mathcal{L} \left[ f(t-c) u(t-c) \right]=e^{-cs}F(s)$$
$$ \mathcal{L} \left[ f(t) u(t-c) \right]=e^{-cs} \mathcal{L} \left[ f(t+c)\right]$$
$$ \int_t^\infty e^{-sx}f(x)dx \space \triangleq  \space \mathcal{L} \left[ f(t) u(t-c) \right] $$